# Unsupported token On CoW Swap

Tags: cow-protocol

I noticed some tokens are indicated to be unsupported when I try to trade then on CoW Swap.
In some cases this happens even with tokens that were already tradable in the past which does not make sense.

What is the explanation and how this can be resolved?

(A concrete example is this token `0x0F7B3F5a8FeD821c5eb60049538a548dB2D479ce` which used to be okay and is now indicated as unsupported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see the reason why a token is not supported you can open the Developer Console (e.g. CMD-Option-I for Brave on Mac) and navigate to the network tab. There, you should see a failed call to `quote` returning a 400 error (see screenshot). If you click on this cell and then chose "preview" you see the plain-text reason for why the token is unsupported.

[image]

In this case the `token is explicitly deny listed`.  Denylisted tokens aren't supported for some technical reason (e.g. custom transfer logic, conditional fee on transfer) and it is unlikely to be fixed.

If you think this is incorrect, please reach out on Discord.

Other reasons (such as not finding an account with sufficient balance or unexpected results from transferring the tokens) can potentially be fixed by making sure the token doesn't charge a fee and giving sufficient balance to a well known contract - e.g. the Balancer Vault or a Uni v2 pool, so the protocol can simulate trades).